# React redux sortable right way

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my project I use react, redux and react-beatuful-dnd for drag-and-drop.
Project has a lists with tasks (as a trello like).
After  drag task and drop it I calculate position:

- If is the first position - start element position / 2
- If last - last element position + 1000
- If middle - (before element position + after element position) / 2

It's work, but is there some simple way to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Am using same react dnd in a project and can't make any sense out of what you are asking or what position calculations you are needing to do. All I ever have to do is splice arrays based on source or destination index from drag end. Providing some sample code and a better explanation would help

Comment: Many thanks. But what values do you send on the server? Destination item and source item? In a 'calculate way' I need send only one item (which drop)

Comment: My droppable ID's are object ID's stored in mongodb. Each has an array of child item objectID's. I send id of moved item along with `result` object from drag end and do same splicing server side as I do in local arrays